# C# Treeview error Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, treeview, runtime-error

I have a treeview and when I press my up arrow which should move the node up I get randomly the error Attempted to read or write protected memory. Theo following code is my up button click event

```
void pbUp_Click(object sender, PActionEventArgs e)
{
    int nIndex = 0;
    int nPrevIndex = 0;
    //Setting the node to the node being moved up.
    FavoriteTreeNode node = tvFavorites.SelectedNode as FavoriteTreeNode;
    nIndex = node.Index;
    FavoriteTreeNode prevNode = null;
    FavoriteTreeNode parentNode = null;
    try
    {
        if (node.Level > 0 && node.Index > 0 )
        {
            //Retrieving the parent node of the favorite if there is on.
            parentNode = node.Parent as FavoriteTreeNode;
            nPrevIndex = nIndex - 1;
            prevNode = parentNode.Nodes[nPrevIndex] as FavoriteTreeNode;
        }
        // the node is the first child of the parent we need to get the parents previous node to insert.
        else if (node.Level > 0 && node.Index == 0)
        {
            parentNode = node.Parent as FavoriteTreeNode;
            //Retrieving the previous node to the selected node being moved.
            nPrevIndex = parentNode.Index - 1;
            prevNode = tvFavorites.Nodes[nPrevIndex] as FavoriteTreeNode;
        }
        else
        {
            nPrevIndex = nIndex - 1;
            prevNode = tvFavorites.Nodes[nPrevIndex] as FavoriteTreeNode;
        }
        //Setting what type of node we are dealing with a folder or favorite.
        if (node.FavoriteType == FavoriteType.Folder.ToString())
        {
                //If the node index is greater than 0 then we know there are nodes above the 
            //currently selected node.
            if (nIndex > 0)
            {
                //Retrieving the previous node to the selected node being moved.
                nPrevIndex = nIndex - 1;
                prevNode = tvFavorites.Nodes[nPrevIndex] as FavoriteTreeNode;
                //Removing the current selected node
                tvFavorites.Nodes.RemoveAt(nIndex);
                //Inserting folder into the previous nodes index. The treeview automatically re-indexes the values.
                tvFavorites.Nodes.Insert(nPrevIndex, node);
            }
        }
        // We are dealing with a favorite.
        else if (node.FavoriteType == FavoriteType.Favorite.ToString())
        {
            //If the previous node is a favorite then we can just move the node up.
            if (prevNode.FavoriteType == FavoriteType.Favorite.ToString())
            {
                if (parentNode != null && node.Index > 0)
                {
                    parentNode.Nodes.RemoveAt(nIndex);
                    parentNode.Nodes.Insert(nPrevIndex, node);
                }
                //The node is under a parent and is the first child.
                else if (parentNode != null && node.Index == 0)
                {
                    parentNode.Nodes.RemoveAt(nIndex);
                    node.ParentPtid = 0;
                    tvFavorites.Nodes.Insert(parentNode.Index, node);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Removing the currently selected node.
                    tvFavorites.Nodes.RemoveAt(nIndex);
                    //Inserting folder into the previous nodes index. The treeview automatically re-indexes the values.
                    tvFavorites.Nodes.Insert(nPrevIndex, node);
                }
              }
              else
              {
                if (parentNode != null)
                {
                    //Removing node from parent node
                    parentNode.Nodes.RemoveAt(nIndex);
                    //Setting the nodes parent ptid to the folder the node is moving to ptid.
                    node.ParentPtid = prevNode.Ptid;
                    prevNode.Nodes.Add(node);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Removing the current selected node
                    tvFavorites.Nodes.RemoveAt(nIndex);
                    parentNode = prevNode;
                    //Setting the nodes parent ptid to the folder ID to indicate the favorite belongs to the folder.
                    node.ParentPtid = parentNode.Ptid;
                    //parentNode doesn't have any children so just add the favorite to the node.
                    parentNode.Nodes.Add(node);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    tvFavorites.ExpandAll();
    node.TreeView.SelectedNode = node;
    tvFavorites.Focus();        //WI#18749
}
```

The output gives me the following.
First-chance exception at 0x77202c16 (ntdll.dll) in phoenix.client.teller.start.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000002c4.
A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
An exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1cb4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1804) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Environment.GetResourceStringLocal'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException.TargetInvocationException'
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1ca4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Main Thread' (0x1c84) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xedc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x468) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x104c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1d88) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1d0c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1d04) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1cc8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1cc0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1cac) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1ca0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1d10) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1d08) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1ccc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

It wont pull up the stacktrace when I am settingt he below options debug unmanaged

Call Stack 
    ntdll.dll!_KiFastSystemCallRet@0()
    ntdll.dll!_ZwWaitForSingleObject@12()  + 0xc bytes
    KernelBase.dll!_WaitForSingleObjectEx@12()  + 0x6c bytes
    kernel32.dll!_WaitForSingleObjectExImplementation@12()  + 0x43 bytes
    msvcr100_clr0400.dll!@_EH4_CallFilterFunc@8()  + 0x12 bytes 
    user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()  + 0x23 bytes
    user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()  + 0xb3 bytes
    user32.dll!*DispatchClientMessage@20()  + 0x4b bytes

    user32.dll!*__fnDWORD@4()  + 0x24 bytes 
    ntdll.dll!_KiUserCallbackDispatcher@12()  + 0x2e bytes
    user32.dll!_DispatchClientMessage@20()
    user32.dll!_NtUserMessageCall@28()  + 0xc bytes 
    user32.dll!_SendMessageWorker@20()  - 0x3853 bytes
    user32.dll!_SendMessageW@16()  + 0x49 bytes 
    [External Code]

> Phoenix.Client.AdGbFavorite.dll!Phoenix.Client.AdGbFavorite.frmFavorites.pbUp_Click(object sender, Phoenix.Windows.Forms.PActionEventArgs e) Line 404 + 0x21 bytes  C#

Comment: This is a wall of inscrutable code that seems to have little to do with the exception.  Enable unmanaged debugging and the Microsoft Symbol Server and post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: The exception happens on teh removeat line of code. I will turn on the above and post. thanks!

Comment: Hans I cant seem to get the stack trace I just get An exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. then I have break continue ignore buttons.

Comment: Click Break.  Then Debug + Windows + Call Stack.